# Selection over different columns after a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max, pandas-loc

I am new to pandas and hence please treat this question with patience
I have a Df with year, state and population data collected over many years and across many states

I want to find the max pop during any year and the corresponding state

example:

```
1995 Alabama xx; 1196 New York yy; 1997 Utah zz
```

I did a groupby and got the population for all the states in a year; How do i iterate over all the years

```
state_yearwise = df.groupby(["Year", "State"])["Pop"].max()
state_yearwise.head(10)
1990  Alabama        22.5
      Arizona        29.4
      Arkansas       16.2
      California     34.1

2016 South Dakota     14.1
     Tennessee        10.2
     Texas            17.4
     Utah             16.1
```

Now I did

```
df.loc[df.pop  == df.pop.max(), ["year", "State", "pop"]]

1992    Colorado  54.1
```

give me only 1 year and the max over all years and states
What I want is per year which state had the max population

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use transform to get the max for each column and get the index of the corresponding pop

```
idx = df.groupby(['year'])['pop'].transform(max) == df['pop']
```

Now you can index the df using idx

```
df[idx]
```

You get

```
    pop state   year
2   210 B   2000
3   200 B   2001
```

For the other dataframe that you updated

```
    Year    State       County  Pop
0   2015    Mississippi Panola  6.4
1   2015    Mississippi Newton  6.7
2   2015    Mississippi Newton  6.7
3   2015    Utah        Monroe  12.1
4   2013    Alabama     Newton  10.4
5   2013    Alabama     Georgi  4.2

idx = df.groupby(['Year'])['Pop'].transform(max) == df['Pop']

df[idx]
```

You get

```
    Year    State   County  Pop
3   2015    Utah    Monroe  12.1
4   2013    Alabama Newton  10.4
```

Comment: I do not think`.pop` will work ....cause pop is a function in pandas...

Comment: pop is working but anyway as pop() is a function, the better practice would be to use ['pop']

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'state' : 'A', 'year' : 2000, 'pop' : 100},
    {'state' : 'A', 'year' : 2001, 'pop' : 110},
    {'state' : 'B', 'year' : 2000, 'pop' : 210},
    {'state' : 'B', 'year' : 2001, 'pop' : 200}])
maxpop = df.groupby("state",as_index=False)["pop"].max()
pd.merge(maxpop,df,how='inner')
```

I see for `df`:

```
    pop state year
0   100 A     2000
1   110 A     2001
2   210 B     2000
3   200 B     2001
```

And for the final result:

```
  state pop year
0   A   110 2001
1   B   210 2000
```

Proof this works:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for showing the concept of merge; However i tried it and i do not get the same result after the "merge".  It does not pick the max state for each year like yours did
0 2015 February Mississippi Newton County 6.1
1 2015 February Mississippi Panola County 9.4
2 2015 February Mississippi Monroe County 7.9
3 2015 February Mississippi Hinds County           5.3

Comment: Show us what you get. Show also the output of df and maxpop. Preferably in a readable format.

Comment: I am adding the tables, in a proper format, but it is getting mangled; let me try again

Comment: {|
|Year||State||County|| Pop ||more
|-
|2015|| Mississippi || Panola || 6.4 ||more
|-
|2015|| Mississippi | | Newton | | 6.7 | | more
|-
|2015|| Mississippi | | Newton | | 6.7 | | more
|-
|2015|| Utah | | Monroe | | 12.1| | more
|-
|2013|| Alabama | | Newton | | 10.4| | more
|-
|2013|| Alabama | | Georgi| | 4.2 | | more
|}

Answer (score 1):

Why not get rid of group by ? By using `sort_values` and `drop_duplicates`

```
df.sort_values(['state','pop']).drop_duplicates('state',keep='last')
Out[164]: 
   pop state  year
1  110     A  2001
2  210     B  2000
```